# How does the differential equation change to account for this half life problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently studying the textbook *Ordinary Differential Equations* by Morris Tenenbaum and Harry Pollard. The section **LESSON 1. How Differential Equations Originate.** has the following two exercise:

> 1. The radium in a piece of lead decomposes at a rate which is proportional to the amount present. If 10 percent of the radium decomposes in 200 years, what percent of the original amount of radium will be present in a piece of lead after 1000 years?
> 2. Assume that the half life of the radium in a piece of lead is 1600 years. How much radium will be lost in 100 years?

The answer to 1. is said to be 59.05 percent, and the answer to 2. is said to be 4.2 percent.

The differential equation for 1. was $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -kx$, where $x$ is the amount of radium. Half life is defined to be the time taken for the amount of substance to fall to half its original value. So how does the differential equation change to account for this half life problem?

Comment: When you solve the DE, you can then use the knowledge about the half-life (or alternatively any information you have about the rate of decay) to find a value of $k$.

Comment: @ConMan Please explain why, because this isn't clear to me.

Comment: Assuming you've solved the DE to get $x = x_0 e^{-kt}$, where $x_0$ is the original amount of the substance, then you can substitute, for example, $t = 200$ and $x = 0.9 x_0$ and solve for $k$.

Comment: @ConMan Yes, but that's just the same as the original differential equation from problem 1. How do we take into account the half life aspect?

Comment: @ThePointer $\frac12\cdot x_0=x(1600)\Rightarrow \frac12\cdot x_0=x_0\cdot e^{-k\cdot 1600}$ // $x_0$ can be "cancelled". Then calculate $k$.

Comment: @callculus42 Let's start from the beginning, so that I can clearly understand how everything is derived. How is $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -kx$ altered to account for the half life aspect of problem 2.? The differential equation is the starting point of such a problem, so we should start our reasoning there.

Comment: Remember that problem 1. says that "the radium in a piece of lead decomposes at a rate which is proportional to the amount present," so the first question becomes how the half life aspect alters this, and so alters the differential equation.

Comment: @ThePointer The half-live condition is a so-called **initial condition**. This cannot be used  at the differential equation. After you have evaluated the function from the differential equation you can use the initial condition as shown above.

Comment: @callculus42 Oh, I see. So how do we factor it into the initial condition? When $t = 0$, we ... ?

Comment: @ThePointer The intial condition must not be at $t=0$. It can be as well at $t=1600$, for instance. Here the initial condition is $x(1600)=\frac12\cdot x_0$.

Comment: @callculus42 But I don't think that's how initial conditions work. An initial condition should state something like "when $t = 0$ (or $t = 1600$), we have that ... ." Using algebraic manipulations and then integration, we get from $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -kx$ to $x = Ae^{-kt}$; so where do we go from here?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes. **If** t=1600, **then**  the half of the initial amount of radium is lost.  // "*....so where do we go from here?*" See my comment 36 min ago.

Comment: @callculus42 I still don't see how what you're saying makes sense. Using the information from 1., when $t = 1600$, we get $$\dfrac{1}{2} x_0 = x_0 e^{-1600(0.0005268)},$$ since we found in 1. that $k = 0.0005268$. But if we perform the cancellations, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: And note that, from 1., when $t = 0$, we get $x = A = x_0$.

Comment: @ThePointer The second exercise has nothing to do with the first exercise. The values of k is different.  At the second exercise the value for k is $-\ln(0.5)/1600\approx 0.000433217...$. It is maybe a good idea not to write the decimal number.

Comment: @ThePointer I have [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100*e%5E%28-0.000433217*1600%29) an example with the initial amount of $x_0=100$ and $t=1600$. I hope it makes the exercise more comprehensible. After 1600 years the initial of 100 becomes 50.

Comment: @callculus42 Ok, I understand now. I got $Cx = xe^{-(100)(0.00043322)} \Rightarrow C = 0.9576$, so $1 - 0.9576 = 0.0424 = 4.24 \%$ Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ThePointer Nice, that is all clear now. You´re welcome.